# Starfield in HTML with transparent background

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the background of a html5-starfield transparent.
I'm not really a coder; but i think it's hard to do.

http://www.chiptune.com/starfield/starfield.html

http://www.thediscopalace.com/testing.php

Using flash can be a solution but this is not allowed because it also must run on the ipad.
Can somebody give me some tips ? Or other scripts or ideas where i can have a simular effect for using on thediscopalace.com.

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Here's a suggestion: Don't use it. Animation like this is quite annoying and, in this case at least, quite useless. Plus, for an effect that relies on mouse position, how are you going to get this to work on the iPad?

Comment: The mouse position-effect is not a must. It's mainly about the stars itself. It's a clients request.

Answer (score 2):

Try this..hope this will be helpful for you.

```
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(150,180,200, .10)"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure and I can't be bothered to test this, but try changing `context.fillStyle='rgb(36,14,118)'` to `context.fillStyle='rgba(0,0,0,0)';`

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I changed before also the fillStyle; then the stars turned into long lines as you can see here:http://www.thediscopalace.com/testing1.php

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the source for the page you can see that the canvas tag has a background color set as rgb. Set it to rgba with the final value being 0 and that should work.

I just used Firebug to change body onmousedown function to a different color and changed the canvas rgb to `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` and when you click the page the background color changes.

So I guess add the following to your starfield or canvas css:

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Hope that helps.

Edit tried it on your page and it didn't work. I guess you changed the Javascript. Saved the page and just changed this line:

```
context.fillStyle='rgb(36,14,118)';
```

to

```
context.fillStyle='rgba(36,14,118, 0)';
```

As also suggested.

Comment: Thanks Billy for your reacting. The background is now transparent. Now i need to find a solution for the stripes in the canves. Thanks !